# how to always place elements at the end of an std::map?

Tags: c++, c++14

So I am wondering how I can insert an element at the back of an std::map, or if there is a similar data structure that I can use, preferably from the STL.

I have tried:

map.insert(map.end(), element);

But it doesn't seem to put the elements in in the correct order all the time.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use `vector` and `push_back`.

Answer (score 2):

std::map is an ordered container. elements will always be inserted as per the order

The iterator you pass to `map::insert` is just a hint and does not force the new element to be inserted at that position within the map container (the elements in a map always follow a specific order depending on their key).

> if there is a similar data structure that I can use, preferably from the STL.

Similar to what? What do you want to do with the data structure?

Answer (score 0):

> how to always place elements at the end of an std::map?

By always inserting an element that compares higher than any pre-existing element.

> But it doesn't seem to put the elements in in the correct order all the time.

The elements will always be in the sorted order. This is the "correct" order for the map. If this is not the "correct" order for you, then std::map is not the correct container for you.

> Is there a way to do this?

Not using std::map.

> if there is a similar data structure that I can use, preferably from the STL.

Depends on how similar data structure you are looking for. You can insert elements in an arbitrary order into a std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best thing to do is put the items in a vector. And then place the key of the element and its index in a map.

```
std::map<string, std::size_type> idx_map;
std::vector elements;
elements.push_back(el_value);
std::size_type idx = elements.size();
idx_map[el_key] = idx;
```

to enumerate in order you must enumerate elements, to lookup use the map to get the index of the value, then get that from the elements vector